# Failed to load NativeSystemBLAS on worker node, but succeeded on master node

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Mllib on a cluster using spark standalone model. 
I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java#machine-optimised-system-libraries) to use MKL within netlib-java.

From worker node log file, I got this error:

```
WARN com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from:
com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS

WARN com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from:
com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

However, MKL integration succeeded on master node.

Does anyone have ANY idea what is causing this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what exactly this warning is about, but I've found that it's harmless.

Comment: I would not go as far to say it is "harmless". Not utilizing BLAS libraries can cost you an enormous amount of additional computation time, especially if you are utilizing heavy math operations like eigendecompositions and such.